# Directory walker written in Go stops with file in use (locked) error

Tags: windows, file, go, directory

I have this directory walker:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
)

var exts = [...]string{"*.psd", "*.cdr", "*.tiff", "*.svg", "*.png", "*.jpeg", "*.jpg", "*.pdf", "*.txt", "*.rtf", "*.docx", "*.doc", "*.xlsx", "*.xls", "*.ppt", "*.pptx", "*.accdb", "*.csv", "*.dwg", "*.dxf", "*.dng", "*.arw", "*.srf", "*.sr2", "*.bay", "*.crw", "*.cr2", "*.dcr", "*.kdc", "*.erf", "*.mef", "*.mrw", "*.nef", "*.nrw", "*.orf", "*.raf", "*.raw", "*.rwl", "*.rw2", "*.r3d", "*.ptx", "*.pef", "*.srw"}
var skipdir = [...]string{"WINDOWS", "Program Files"}

func VisitFile(fp string, fi os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    proceed := true
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err) // can't walk here,
        return nil       // but continue walking elsewhere
    }
    if fi.IsDir() {
        return nil // not a file.  ignore.
    }
    for _, value := range skipdir {
        if strings.Contains(filepath.Dir(fp), value) {
            proceed = false
            break
        }
    }
    if proceed == true {
        for _, value := range exts {
            matched, err := filepath.Match(value, fi.Name())
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err) // malformed pattern
                return err       // this is fatal.
            }
            if matched {
                fmt.Println(fp)
            }
        }
    } else {
        //fmt.Println(proceed)
        return nil
    }
    return nil
}

func getdrives() (r []string) {
    for _, drive := range "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" {
        _, err := os.Open(string(drive) + ":\\")
        if err == nil {
            r = append(r, string(drive))
        }
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    drives := getdrives()
    for _, value := range drives {
        filepath.Walk(value+":/", VisitFile)
    }
}
```

However, when it gets to pagefile.sys, I get this message:

> GetFileAttributesEx C:\pagefile.sys: The process cannot access the file because
>       it is being used by another process.

because the file is in use, and program stops. How do I suppress this message to continue walking?

Comment: Quick note: `if proceed == true` can be reduced to `if proceed`.

Comment: This may require some Windows specific syscalls. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/mQnKRPuHvEQ

Comment: Can you add to your question which line it is that it stops at? There is probably an easier way to skip over these locked files without resorting to difficult syscalls.

Comment: Please provide a stacktrace on any pastebin resource and update your question with a link to it.  Also please tell us your Go version.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your walk to finish, you should not return the error inside your function. You should collect the errors inside a slice.
Change your function to:

```
// Put this var outside your function
var myErrors []error
func VisitFile(fp string, fi os.FileInfo, err error) []error {
```

Just make a variable as slice of errors. And then change the `return err`

```
   if proceed == true {
        for _, value := range exts {
            matched, err := filepath.Match(value, fi.Name())
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err) // malformed pattern
                // collect the error
                myErrors = append(myErrors,err)
                // you could jump out of this by 
                return nil
            }
            if matched {
                fmt.Println(fp)
            }
        }
    }
```

At the end you can check the `myErrors` slice.

Comment: By caller you mean filepath.Walk?

Comment: You will have to make `myErrors` a global variable here. It is `filepath.Walk` calling the `VisitFile` function. But I like the idea, you get the files walked, then you can inspect the errors afterward.